# Never receive user-media updates via Instagram real-time subscription

Tags: instagram

I have little hope anyone from Instagram monitors SO but who knows...

Do you guys use [Real-time](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) photo updates from Instagram ? I never receive user-media updates. I successfully subscribe to it, Instagram sends to my server HTTP GET confirmation call to which I replay and never receive any updates after.

Thoughts ?

Comment: How do you know you aren't getting updates?  Have you checked that your subscription is calling the correct URL using:  `https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&client_id=CLIENT_ID`.  Also keep in mind you will not receive updates from accounts that are private.

Comment: @cdbconcepts I know I'm not getting updates because my callback url is never called :) I tested it with public account. But the problem is Instagram. There is thread in their Google Groups which indicates Real-Time updates are broken since at least May (!!!) and Instagram doesn't seem to give a shit :)

Comment: That's weird.  I can confirm that my real-time updates are still working.  Hope your issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The updates came in the body, not in the POST... then you must do some trick to get it:

```
$file = fopen("data.txt","a");
fwrite($file,"\r\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." \r\n");
if (count($_GET)>0)
    fwrite($file,"\r\nGET:\r\n".print_r($_GET,true));
if (count($_POST)>0)
    fwrite($file,"\r\nPOST:\r\n".print_r($_POST,true));
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
fwrite($file,"\r\nINPUT DECODED:\r\n".print_r($decoded,true));
fclose($file);
```